# Regex to match a definition of a javascript function and making sure it returns something?

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I need to make sure that some submitted  code has a function named `mapfn` defined, and that that function returns a result. I came up with the following regex expression:
`mapfn\s+?\=\s+?function\s+?\(split\)\s+?\{.+?return\(result\).+?\}` which matches something like

```
mapfn = function (split) {
    var i = 5+4;
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        i += j*Math.random()*10;
    }
    var result = i;
    return(result)
}
```

Which is desirable but if I go to for an example closure compiler with this code and get something like `mapfn=function(){for(var b=9,a=0;a<10;a++)b+=a*Math.random()*10;return b};`, that regex is useless. Also, the user submits something like

```
function mapfn (split) {
    var i = 5+4;
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        i += j*Math.random()*10;
    }
    var result = i;
    return(result)
}
```

Then the regex is also useless.

I feel there's a more elegant solution for this problem than having 5 or 6 regular expressions for this job and trying to match any one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *totally* impossible to do with a regex.

Consider

```
function x() { if (1 < 0) return 7; }
```

All you can do is parse the function in a Javascript environment, call it, and see what it returns.

If you want to make sure that it *always* returns a value, you'll need to solve the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_Problem).

Comment: But could you write a regex to determine if a code fragment goes into an infinite loop?

Comment: SLacks: What if I specifically tell people that they must do something like function x() { if (1 < 0) result = 7; return(result) } ?

Comment: @João: And then reject any input that doesn't fit that pattern? Also, that won't help.  Just insert `return;` – or, worse, `while(true);` – in the middle.  In fact, your very example won't return anything.

Comment: @João - like SLaks says, it's impossible.  Not just with a regex, it's impossible in general.  If this is a requirement, you really need to reconsider your problem.

Comment: @SLaks, you're right, but peculiarities of JS syntax make it impossible to even tell whether there's any `return` path (reachable or not) within a JS function body without a full parse.  See my answer for your daily dose of line noise.

Answer (score 2):

SLaks is right, but you don't need to invoke the halting problem to prove it's impossible *with regular expressions*.  With a regular expression, you can't even tell whether a JavaScript function contains `return` used as a keyword even if you could match curly brackets to tell where a definition function ends.

Consider

```
function () {
  1 /[/**/]; return 1 ///
}
```

vs

```
function () {
    /[/**/]; return 1 ///  
}
```

The first contains a return because it is equivalent to

```
function () {
  1 / [];
  return 1;
  ///
}
```

but the second does not because it is equivalent to

```
function () {
  new RegExp("[\\/\\*\\*\\/]; return 1 ");
  //
}
```

There can be arbitrarily many characters between the `/*` and `*/` so you need to completely disambiguate the first `/` to tell whether it is a division operator or a regular expression to tell whether the keyword `return` occurs in the function.  That requires a full parse, and JavaScript does not have a regular lexical grammar.

Comment: Wrong.  A sufficiently complex regex can parse comments, regex literals, and string literals (since they can't be nested).  All you can't parse are braces.

Comment: In fact, many environments (including .Net and Perl) support recursive regexes, so you can even parse braces, allowing you to exclude `return`s in nested functions with a _really_ long regex.

Comment: @SLaks, you need an arbitrary number of characters of lookbehind to determine whether a `/` is a division operator or starts a regular expression literal. Consider `(x)/y/i.test(s)` vs `if (x)/y/i.test(s) ` vs `o.if(x)/y/i.test(s)`.  I can keep going.

Comment: @SLaks, to clarify, for each token type there is a regular expression that recognizes that token.  But for every regular expression `r`, there is a `validJavaScriptProgram` such that `validJavaScriptProgram.match(r)` incorrectly tokenizes `validJavaScriptProgram`.

Comment: @SLaks, those recursive regular expressions are not *regular* as defined in parser theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar

Comment: I realize that.  However, they're still common.

Comment: @SLaks, If you limit the discussion to either JS regular expressions (which are only non-regular around backreferences), or regular expressions as defined in terms of finite automata, then JavaScript does not have a regular lexical grammar.